How to update all fields except Table of Contents
I am trying to create a macro 3 different choices for updating fields within a word doc.  I am able to update all of the fields including the ToC and links throughout or the ToC only, but would also like to be able to only update fields that are not the ToC.  Is there a way to select everything but the ToC and then update? Here is the current code I'm running:
Sub RefreshFields()
'
' RefreshFields Macro
'
'
    Dim ToC As TableOfContents

    Select Case InputBox("Update which fields?" & vbCrLf & "Type '1' for all fields" & vbCrLf & "Type '2' for Table of Contents only" & vbCrLf & "Type '3' for all fields except Table of Contents")
    
    Case 1
        Selection.WholeStory
        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        Selection.Fields.Update
        MsgBox ("All fields updated")
        
    Case 2
        For Each ToC In ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
        ToC.Update
        Next
        MsgBox ("Only ToC updated")
        
    Case 3
'
'
'        MsgBox ("All fields except ToC updated")

    End Select
    
End Sub

I tried different function to select the table of contents and pair that with some kind of "except" function but was unable to.


Utilizing the User-Defined Function (UDF) IsFieldInTOC to ascertain whether the field is present in the Table of Contents (TOC) or not.

Option Explicit

Sub RefreshFields()
    Dim fld As Field
    
    Select Case InputBox("Update which fields?" & vbCrLf & "Type '1' for all fields" & vbCrLf & "Type '2' for Table of Contents only" & vbCrLf & "Type '3' for all fields except Table of Contents")
        Case 1
            Selection.WholeStory
            Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
            Selection.Fields.Update
            MsgBox ("All fields updated")
        Case 2
            Dim ToC As TableOfContents
            For Each ToC In ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
                ToC.Update
            Next
            MsgBox ("Only ToC updated")
        Case 3
            For Each fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
                If Not IsFieldInTOC(fld) Then
                    fld.Update
                End If
            Next
            MsgBox ("All fields except ToC updated")
    End Select
End Sub

Function IsFieldInTOC(fld As Field) As Boolean
    Dim ToC As TableOfContents
    Dim fldStart As Long
    Dim fldEnd As Long
    fldStart = fld.Result.Start
    fldEnd = fld.Result.End
    For Each ToC In ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
        If (fldStart >= ToC.Range.Start And fldStart <= ToC.Range.End) _
            Or (fldEnd >= ToC.Range.Start And fldEnd <= ToC.Range.End) Then
            IsFieldInTOC = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next ToC
    IsFieldInTOC = False
End Function


Any reason you’re not using Field.Type https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdfieldtype ?

@TimothyRylatt I knew there is wdFieldTOC. But I don't know how to determin whether the field (wdFieldHyperlink and wdFieldPageRef) is present in the Table of Contents (TOC) or not. Maybe I missed sth.. If ToC.Type <> wdFieldTOC Then ToC.Update updated the page number in TOC.

For case 3 you could use If Not fld.Type = wdFieldTOC then fld.update

But it updates page num in TOC.

It won't if you toggle ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes first, which is always a good idea if you are looping through fields.

Thank you so much @taller for you quick response, it solved my problem exactly!
I am now trying to implement this into a user form with option buttons (the input box always turned off my numlock) but I am receiving a compilation error "ByRef argument type mismatch" when I try to run the code for the user form. I am not sure why I am having trouble calling the boolean function through a type mismatch when it was fine before.  Any advice?

It's hard to answer without knowing your code. What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?
